# How to keep the dropdown list open in robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

[image]

Here, I will click the actions tab and select create new project from the drop down list.

While executing the script in robot framework, after clicking the actions tab the drop down list will be opened and after few seconds it automatically got closed.

I need to know how to keep the list to be in open.

Comment: Does the list close automatically after a few seconds when you do it manually as well? If it doesn't, then try using the [Mouse over](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Mouse%20Over) keyword with the locator of 'Create new Project' option in the drop-down list.

Comment: No it won't close automatically while doing manually. When I click outside the drop down list then only it will be closed.

Comment: Did you try the 'Mouse over' keyword?

Comment: No I didn't tried it. Let me try it once

Comment: Thanks buddy, it is working :) :). Mouse over keyword is working fine

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, what is happening is that the library you use to create the dropdown is designed to dismiss the dropdown when the mouse leaves the dropdown. If that is the case, the solution is to first move the mouse over the dropdown before clicking on it.

The SeleniumLibrary has a [Mouse over](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Mouse%20Over) keyword that will simulate the mouse being over the element.